# Java 8 collecting the list that is already present in object

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I was just searching for better way to handle this scenario using java 8 streams. Object A has list of object b. What I get is a list of object A (List). I need to stream through list of object A and get all the listB's in each of the object A as a one single list.

```
class A {
    List<B> listB
}
```

I have tried the below way it throws compilation

```
List<A> as = someObject.getAs();
List<B> listofBs = as.stream().map(in -> in.getListB()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your example code isn't legal, nor is what you appear to be trying; why do you need to collect an existing `List`?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: I need to collect all the lists of B in each of the object A list using addAll()

Comment: @PaulLemarchand this is the error I get: Incompatible types. Required List<B> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that List<B> conforms to B inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Blower bounds: List<B>

Answer (score 4):

To get a single list of all B's, you should use `flatMap` as:

```
List<B> listOfBs = listOfAs.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A{
  List<B> listB
};
List<A> listA;
listA.stream().map(
 a->{
  //some code for A
  a.ListB.stream().map(
   b->{
    // some code for B
  })
});
```

may be help you